# Иконка игры размытая Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: я нарисовал иконку игры и сбилдил саму игру, затем создал ярлык и поместил его на рабочий стол, но он размытый хотя в самом юнити на на этой иконке я поставил Point (No Filter) в параметре Filter Mode. Сама иконка имеет разрешения 25x25, рисовал в фотошопе. Как убрать размытие иконки игры?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы должны рисовать 64x64 минимум. в иконках используются размеры типа 8x8, 16x16,32x32, 64x64, 96x96, 128x128, 256x256.

Comment: @return я перерисовал иконку в размер 64x64 и результат точно такой же

Comment: если у exec-файла нормальная иконка, а у ярлыка – нет, то виноват ярлык. а так не знаю, что у вас за проблема(

Comment: Может просто сделать набор иконок согласно аннотации с лево и не искать потом корень проблем на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @Yaroslav делал, эффекта - 0

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы убрать размытие иконки игры, достаточно просто нажать на иконку во вкладке Project, поменять его параметры на ПК версию и поставить галочку напротив Ovveride For PC, Mac & Linux Standalone. Затем нажать кнопку Apply для применения настроек.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]